# SWT scale widget - floating point values

Tags: java, widget, swt

How can I display a scale in swt with floating point values?

This is what I have right now

```
    Group groupTime = new Group(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    groupTime.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,true));
    groupTime.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false,false, 1, 1));
    new Label(groupTime, SWT.NONE).setText("Speed in seconds:");

    Scale scale = new Scale (groupTime, SWT.BORDER);
    scale.setMaximum (10);

    Label speedLabel = new Label(groupTime, SWT.NONE);
    speedLabel.setText("time");
    scale.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener ()
    {
        public void handleEvent(Event event)
        {
            speedLabel.setText(scale.getSelection()+"");
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works on integers internally, so you'll have to make it handle floats yourself. This will give you one decimal space:

```
Scale scale = new Scale(shell, SWT.BORDER);
scale.setMaximum(10 * 10);

Label speedLabel = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
speedLabel.setText("time");
scale.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
        speedLabel.setText((scale.getSelection() / 10f) + "");
    }
});
```

If you need more decimal spaces, then a `Scale` really isn't the right widget for you.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thanks :)